# Javascript - Getting and setting properties on primitives implicitly creates object wrappers

Tags: javascript

I was reading a book called **Effective JavaScript: 68 Specific Ways to Harness the Power of JavaScript**, Point 4 Prefer Primitives to Object Wrappers and came across this sentence.

> Getting and setting properties on primitives implicitly creates object
>   wrappers

Does this create an object wrapper?

```
"hello".someProperty = 17;
```

**EDIT**

If the above statement create an object then please explain this behaviour.

```
var test = "foo";
test.bar = "new prop";
test.bar //this prints undefined.
```

Comment: everything is an object

Comment: @CrayonViolent That's not a valid statement...

Comment: No it won't `"hello"` is just string litteral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"hello".someProperty = 17;
```

The above statement does create an object wrapper, but it is disposed of as soon as its task is done.

```js
var hello = 'Hello';
hello.someProperty = 17;
console.log(hello.someProperty);
```

This explains why trying to assign properties to a primitive doesn't work, but also doesn't throw an error. Assigning the property succeeds, but the property is set on a wrapper object which is immediately destroyed. So when you go to look up the property later, there is nothing there anymore.

Internally, `this` of primitive type is `object`.

```js
String.prototype.thisType = function () {
    return typeof this;
};
var hello = "hello";

console.log(typeof hello);
console.log(hello.thisType());
```

Read more [Here](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/javascripts-primitive-wrapper-objects.html)

Comment: Does `var a = ''` creates string object or literal? Please refer [String spec - 15.5.1.1](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5)

Comment: A function's *this* is set by how you call the function (except for arrow functions and use of bind), it's not static. In this case, it will return the *typeof* of the temporary object created during the evaluation of the expression (as described [*in the spec*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-property-accessors)). ;-)

Comment: @RobG I console logged `this` inside the `thisType`, it referred to String object. I also modified the `thisType` to return `this` and `console.log(hello.thisType() === this);` which returned `false`.

Comment: @HassanImam—not sure what `console.log(hello.thisType() === this)` is attempting to show. *thisType* returns a string, while in global code *this* is the global object. So not only different types, but different values so a strict equality test should return false. The good part is that you found a way to show the temporary object created during evaluation of the expression.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it creates an intermediate object, which is discarded after use. So the statement

```
"hello".someProperty = 17;
```

will internally be executed like this:

```
var temp = new String("hello");  // or any other variable name
temp.someProperty = 17;
```

So, now `temp` (or whatever named variable is created by JavaScript) will not be accessible because it is created and discarded immediately.

Comment: how can I see this internal object creation thing?  I mean i need to see the code by my eyes. please provide some good resource so that i can be rest assured.

Comment: What about `var a = 1; a.foo='foo'`?

Comment: This is the spec for [string](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5)

Comment: @Rajesh—that's an old specification for String objects, the grammar for property accessors is [*here*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-property-accessors).

Comment: @RobG Considering the fact ES6 still is not supported everywhere, i thought it would be apt to check ES5 spec.

Comment: @Li357 -- I tried to benchmark it using jsPerf, but it doesn't give details about number of intermediate objects :/ Any other tool in mind?

Comment: @Rajesh—yeah, none of the fundamentals have changed but the language used in the spec has. I think it's a lot harder to read now… ;-)

Comment: @JohnDoe—see the second code example in Hassan's answer.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create String Object by new Keyword.

```
var str = new String("My String");
//Here str is looks like
//String {"My String"}
str .xyz=5
str 
//now String {"My String", xyz: 5}
```

Comment: I prefer Primitives than object wrapper. 

    var s1 = new String("hello");
    var s2 = new String("hello");
    s1 === s2; // false
    s1 == s2; // false too