# JavaScript: Why does false.something evaluate to undefined?

Tags: javascript

While learning about the optional chaining operator I experimented a bit and found out that these two evaluate to undefined:

```
false.nonExistingProperty // undefined
true.nonExistingProperty // undefined
```

But why is that so? Shouldn't this throw an error?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53149349/how-does-primitive-types-in-javascript-have-methods-and-properties, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47935826/javascript-getting-and-setting-properties-on-primitives-implicitly-creates-obj, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751704/javascript-do-primitive-strings-have-methods

Answer (score 9):

> When properties are accessed on primitives, JavaScript auto-boxes the value into a wrapper object and accesses the property on that object instead.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive

`false` and `true` are implicitly converted to `Boolean` objects here, i.e. you are reading `nonExistingProperty` from a `Boolean` instead of the boolean primitive.

Answer (score -1):

In JavaScript, when you try to access a property on a primitive value like false, JavaScript internally coerces the primitive value to an object using the concept of object wrappers. These object wrappers are temporary objects created around primitive values to allow you to access properties and methods on them.

When you try to access a non-existing property on false like false.nonExistingProperty, JavaScript creates an object wrapper around the false primitive value. However, since there is no property named nonExistingProperty on this object, the result of the expression is undefined

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).